# Is there Database diagram of Typo3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have to migrate my custom system to typo3 version 6.2 but I did not find any database diagram(design/schema) of typo3. Would be great if someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a TYPO3 installation without extensions, there are not many tables that will interest you. Interesting tables are

- `pages` and `pages_language_overlay`: Pages and their translations.
- `tt_content`: Content, translations are in the same table.
- `sys_language`: Define available languages. For pages with only a default language it can stay  empty.
- `sys_domain`: Define Domains under which a site is available. For single domain installations it can be left empty.
- `sys_file_reference`: References to files, which are stored in table `sys_files`.  The table `sys_files` will be automatically filled when you put files into the fileadmin folder.
- `fe_users` and `fe_groups`: Frontend users and groups.

The other tables are either caching tables (names start with `cf_`) or are mostly used internally (most tables having names starting with `sys_`).

In some of the tables, especially in `pages` and `tt_content`, there are deprecated fields.

The usage of some fields depends on the actual TYPO3 setup. For example, the text of a content element from `tt_content` could be stored in the field `bodytext`, or in the field `pi_flexform`. So the question how to import your data depends on your setup.

For further information have a look at the official docs: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/latest/ApiOverview/Database/DatabaseStructure/Index.html

Comment: It's exactly what I searched for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a diagram either, but this note is too long for a comment:

Most M:N relationships (e.g. users & groups) are handled with foreign key attributes stored as comma-separated entries inside table cells, inside rows of the parent table. Of course, this nonatomic way of storing data violates first-normal form of database-table design.

However, some newer extensions *do* rely on bridge tables. In typo3, this is called an M:M relation, and some tables have a naming corresponding convention, e.g. tt_news_cat_mm, linking news-messages with news-categories.